# Using Outlook via MS Activesync?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, activesync

I sync to my work Outlook using activesync. This account has all of my contacts (work and private) and Calendar (work and private) combined. This works well for my phone (Android 4.x) and my laptop (Win 8.1) each using their specific mail and calendar clients.

I have Outlook on the laptop and would prefer to use that to manage my calendar and contacts, but I cannot seem to configure it to my work account. My work will not allow me to directly connect to the server, but only use the mail for exchange activesync program.

Is there any way to use Outlook to add/edit/delete entries on my Win 8.1 laptop only connecting through Activesync?

Comment: What version of Outlook is in question?  What version of Exchange?

Comment: Outlook is part of Office Professional Plus 2013.  Are you asking about the Exchange Server at work (how do I find out) or the Mail for Exchange account setting, which I cannot now find the settings/program for on my Win8.1 system.